# How can I access events data for a place in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I wanted to use Google Places API to get nearby places (music venues, pubs, theaters, etc.) in given city, then look for events in these places. And if you look at some places on google maps, you can see that there is a section 'Upcoming Events', so I'm sure the data is here. The problem is, Place Details endpoint does not provide with such information, although upon some research I found some information that told me otherwise, namely [this](https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2012/05/events-support-in-google-places-api.html), however I am aware that this information is pretty old at best. My question is - is this feature of API still available, or was it removed, or what?

Currently what I'm doing is first sending the request like this:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key={api_key}&location={city}&radius={some_radius}`

to get all the places available, then for each place_id in response:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key={key}&placeid={place_id}`

The fields in these responses are not including any info about events, even if the place have the section 'Upcoming Events' on google maps.

Comment: Are there any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a feature request for Events API in the Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137032001

I would suggest staring the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications from Google. Hopefully one day they implement this API and expose events via APIs.